# Delete command in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am aware of only truncate command in sqlplus,

```
connect myuser/mypassword@myserver
truncate table mytable;

EXIT;
/
```

Wondering if there is a delete command, I read about DEL but not sure how to use it appropriately, please advice if there is something to use like the below in sqlplus if any,

```
delete from mytable where emp_id in (1,5);
```

Comment: I will answer your question, but first a polite rant. Please google such things before asking here. StackOverflow requires you to show some effort on your part. If StackOverflow is going to be your resource for asking such questions, you will have a hard time programming. Even a simple search like "delete command plsql" gives you so many good results.

Comment: `truncate` and `delete` are not SQL\*Plus commands. They are SQL commands.  SQL\*Plus is just one of many clients that allow you to query an Oracle database using SQL commands. I say this so that you know what to search for when googling for help on these topics.

Comment: What you show in your question seems to be a SQL*Plus script. SQL commands, like truncate... and delete..., are terminated with semicolon (;). SQL*Plus commends, like connect... and EXIT, are terminated by a newline. No need for ; after EXIT.

Comment: In fact, I already did lots of search on Google but couldn't quite figure out this one. This forum is my last option, otherwise I don't simply put some questions to get backlashes. Anyway, I am not giving up yet, still googling, thanks for all your responses and inputs.

Comment: This is all explained in the Oracle SQL reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm and https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is yes.
In fact, what you have written is a perfectly valid delete command.
See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/delete.php for a simple tutorial and guide. Not just Oracle, but all SQL databases support it. It is part of the SQL language itself.